# Missing php8.1-curl package

Tags: php, ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to install the `php8.1-curl` package on my system - `Ubuntu 21.04`. I've added the Ondřej Surý's repository (`add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`), performed `apt update` and I'm able to install `php8.1` and many other extensions (e.g. `php8.1-zip`) via `apt install php8.1...`, but not `php8.1-curl` for some reason.

```
> sudo apt install php8.1-curl
...
E: Unable to locate package php8.1-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-curl'
```

How should I go about troubleshooting this issue? Where can I look for the package and why it's missing on my system?

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: @medilies: I've added the error message to the question.

Comment: The repository isn't set correctly

Comment: @IMSoP: Sorry, that was a typo. I did `apt update`. I've edited the question.

Comment: @medilies: What do you mean by that? How would I check if it is set correctly?

Comment: The meaning of this message `E: Unable to locate package php8.1-curl` is that there is an issue with locating the package in known repositories https://itsfoss.com/unable-to-locate-package-error-ubuntu/. Excuse me for being a little bit lazy with your issue but I recommend using Docker.

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove and re-add ondrej/php repository

Update the system

```
apt-get update -y
```

Check the package

```
apt-cache search php8.1-curl
```

You should see output like this

> php8.1-curl - CURL module for PHP